# Cache updating error

Tags: 14.04, updates

I am unable to download many software from Ubuntu Software Center. It shows an error saying-
**"Package dependencies cannot be resolved"**
As I am a new user so I searched the solution which said that changing the Download from option in Software and updates from Server for 'Country to Main server and then installing updates will help. But on doing so this error came-
A pop screen came saying **Failed to download repository information** after reloading. When I viewed details it showed following error-
**E:GPG error: https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 2**.

Please answer this question and it is a request that do not mark this question as duplicate because previous answers were not helpful to me.

Please Help.
Thanks in Advance.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, url_for, redirect
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import subprocess

mediaConnect = Flask(__name__)
CORS(mediaConnect, support_credentials = True)

@mediaConnect.route('/listFlows', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@cross_origin(origin = '*', headers = ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'], support_credentials = True)
def listFlows():
    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        userInput = request.get_json()

        command = 'aws mediaconnect list-flows --region ' + userInput['region']
        pipe = subprocess.Popen(command, shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
        stdout = pipe.communicate()

        return stdout

@mediaConnect.route('/createFlow', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@cross_origin(origin = '*', headers = ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'], support_credentials = True)
def createFlow():
    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        userInput = request.get_json()

        command = 'aws mediaconnect create-flow --region ' + userInput['region'] + ' --availability-zone ' + userInput['az'] + ' --name ' + userInput['name'] + ' --source Description="' + userInput['description'] + ',IngestPort=' + userInput['ingestPort'] + ',Name=' + userInput['sourceName'] + ',Protocol=' + userInput['protocol'] + ',WhitelistCidr=' + userInput['whitelistCidr']
        pipe = subprocess.Popen(command, shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
        stdout = pipe.communicate()

        return stdout

@mediaConnect.route('/describeFlow', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@cross_origin(origin = '*', headers = ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'], support_credentials = True)
def describeFlow():
    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        userInput = request.get_json()

        command = 'aws mediaconnect describe-flow --region ' + userInput['region'] + ' --flow-arn ' + userInput['flowArn']
        pipe = subprocess.Popen(command, shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
        stdout = pipe.communicate()

        return stdout

@mediaConnect.route('/deleteFlow', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@cross_origin(origin = '*', headers = ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'], support_credentials = True)
def deleteFlow():
    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        userInput = request.get_json()

        command = 'aws mediaconnect delete-flow --region ' + userInput['region'] + ' --flow-arn ' + userInput['flowArn']
        pipe = subprocess.Popen(command, shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
        stdout = pipe.communicate()

        return stdout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mediaConnect.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: Run this sudo -i && apt-get clean && cd /var/lib/apt && mv lists lists.old && mkdir -p lists/partial && apt-get clean && apt-get update

Comment: I tried this command but the problem still persists.

Comment: @Priyansh, could you please add more details to your question, what are you trying to install and link to the questions that you mean by "previous answers were not helpful to me."